# Splitting up files to take advantage of multiple threads, lots of read/write operations

Tags: multithreading, optimization, cpu-cores

I know that similar questions have been asked, though the answer seems to depend highly on the type of operations being performed so I thought I should ask about my specific case here. I'm also brand new to this, so forgive my inexperience.

I have a very large csv file I need to process, about 400 million lines (actually split up over several csv files).  My script reads a line, performs a computation, then writes the result to a separate output csv file.

Each line can be computed independently, so I can split my file up into as many smaller pieces as I'd like.  When I run `lscpu` I get the following:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              32
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-31
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  16
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           AuthenticAMD
CPU family:          23
Model:               1
Model name:          AMD Ryzen Threadripper 1950X 16-Core Processor
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             3692.603
CPU max MHz:         3400.0000
CPU min MHz:         2200.0000
BogoMIPS:            6786.40
Virtualization:      AMD-V
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           64K
L2 cache:            512K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-31
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid amd_dcm aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb hw_pstate sme ssbd vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 rdseed adx smap clflushopt sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif overflow_recov succor smca
```

My  plan was to split my file up into N smaller pieces, then start my process running N separate times (assuming that the N tasks would be sent to different cores if possible).

My question is then: what value of N should I pick?  I have 16 cores, but two threads per core.  Should I run processes using all 32 threads, or just 16?

I ran some test code on a file with 10000 rows, and here's the timing (where the read/write were timed as a single operation):

```
Mean read/write time = 0.0002238105
Mean compute time = 0.0724388522
Total read/write time = 2.238105
Total compute time = 724.388522
```

I don't know how much read/write operations tie up the CPU, so maybe that is not relevant.

Would splitting it up into 32 processes give me a speed-up over 16 processes?  Or will the fact that two processes share each core slow down the individual processes to a point where there is no net speed-up?

Also, if I start 16 or 32 separate processes (using different screen windows) will they be assigned to different cores/threads automatically?  Or do I need to do something to ensure they are spread out?

Comment: io operation from a disk are essentially sequential. They always be your bottleneck.  They are also slow comparing to the calculation speed. If your computation task is tiny, you might not get any win with multiple processes (or even make it worse). If it is big, would be better have just 2 or 3 processes (read, computation, write).  The real win you can get if you split the file between different physical disks. Just do some experiments.

Comment: So when you say "2 or 3 processes" I assume you mean per core?  I'll try some experiments, thanks!

Comment: How big was the file you tested with your test code, and did you clear the disk cache first? Try a reasonably big file (so it takes at least a few seconds to run), and clear the disk cache before running it. If the compute time is still much longer than the IO time, then you should use 1 thread per core.

Comment: @hughes i meant 2-3 processes all together. if computes are really long, you can split them between available cores as well.

Comment: @user253751 I reran the test on a file with 10000 rows, and edited my question above with the results.  Each row involves one read, compute, and write step (I wasn't able to clear the cache, I tried some code to do that I found online but it didn't work).  Based on these results I'm assuming it makes sense just to stick to one process per core, correct?

Comment: Distribution of processes to CPUs is OS-dependent. More so when you talk about threads. Indeed, as @Serge mentioned, odds are high that your task is mostly IO-bound, not CPU-bound, so distributing it over N CPUs isn't going to buy you much time. However, having one subtask that saturates the IO (or two, if it's separate devices) and another for processing may give you an advantage over a task that toggles between being IO-bound and CPU-bound. In any case, you need to measure.

Comment: Since your process is mostly compute, it makes sense to have one process per core.